# Duplicate cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I am setting two cookies in PHP in my root directory

> ```
>    setcookie ("st", "$todays_system_date"  );
>    setcookie ("en", "$tomorrow" );
> ```

My problem is I need to set them again in a script that is in a deeper folder eg: /diary/
When I do set them and then try to read them or look at the cookies set , I find I have 2x en and 2x st cookies .

My question is how can I make reference to just one set of cookies ? and read them ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you also setting the "Cookie Path"? For script in "root" it should be "/" and or sub folder it should be "/diary".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cookies are key/value pairs - they will only ever have a single value in any given scope.

However:

- It is possible to have more than one cookie with the same key and different values for the same domain (although it will still only have one effective value in any given scope).

For example, if you set the cookie `st` in the root (`/`) with the value `1`, and in `/diary/` with value `2`, the two cookies will exist in their own right. When you are in the `/` directory (or any subdirectory of `/` that is not `/diary/` or a subdirectory of `/diary/`) the value will be `1`. When you are in `/diary/` or a subdirectory of `/diary/` if will be `2`:

```
Directory         Cookie Value
/                      1
/somedir/              1
/diary/                2
/diary/subdir          2
/somedir/diary/        1
```

- It is possible to set the same cookie twice in the same scope, but only the later value will be effective - the later value overrides the earlier value.

For example:

```
setcookie('st',1); // st is now 1 for the current path
setcookie('st',2); // st is now 2 for the current path
```

If you look at the HTTP response message that is sent by PHP you will see 2 `Set-Cookie:` headers for the key `st`. However, on the next request within the cookie's scope, only the later value `2` will be sent back to the server.

Comment: If you substitute my "cookies can be a little odd" with this post, you'll understand _why_ cookies can be a little odd ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

Cookies can be a little odd - it *should* work if you set more of the parameters... try:

```
setcookie('st', "{$todays_system_date}", 0, '/', '.yourdomain.ext');
setcookie('en', "{$tomorrow}", 0, '/', '.yourdomain.ext');
```

It might be that the subsequent cookies are being set with a different path or domain leading to duplication.

n.b. if you use `'.yourdomain.ext'` (note the . before your domain) the cookie will be accessible through all subdomains on your site, so `www.yourdomain.ext` or `badger.yourdomain.ext` and so on.

For more information see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php