# Codeigniter 2.x response header set cookies duplicated

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

There are a lot of `ci_session=xxxx`, `ci_session=xxx`, `ci_session=xxxx` (some of the pages up to 10 "`ci_session`")

I've tried many ways also not working. I'm unable remove the duplicated headers cookie.

Any CI profession, please advice what can I do? I am using CI 2.x

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255854/codeigniter-session-set-cookie-duplicated-how-to-solve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673510/duplicate-cookies

Comment: I tried your link before, it is not working.

Comment: Have you made any changes in core files?

Comment: Or have you added any third party plugin which works similar like session creation

Comment: No, I did not add any third party plugins. thanks.